# Recovering *permanently* deleted emails from Gmail

Tags: gmail

person in distress here.

Dont ask me how, but I ended up deleting all my 12,000 inbox emails from Gmail into Trash and then erased my Trash as well. Gmail gave me a warning box and took 20 seconds to delete. This was not what I intended. I have searched high and low to check if there is any way of recovering my 10 years worth of emails and could not find any.

Any one here know of a way, ANY WAY, to recover my accidental permanent deletion of all my 10 years worth of email (deleted from Trash as well)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not according to [Google](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78353?hl=en);

> **Recovering deleted messages**
>
> *If you've deleted a message permanently, by clicking Delete Forever in*
>   *your Spam or Trash, you won’t be able to recover the message using the*
>   *Gmail interface.*
>
> In the past, users have reported that they are missing all of their
>   messages as a result of unauthorized access. If your account was
>   compromised and you would like us to investigate whether recovery is
>   possible, please first complete this process to secure your account
>   and then file a report.
>
> If you've moved a message to Trash, by clicking Delete, but it's been
>   fewer than 30 days and you haven't permanently deleted it, follow
>   these steps to put it back in your inbox:
>
> 1. Sign in to Gmail.
> 2. Click Trash along the left side of any Gmail page. (If you don't see Trash along the left side of your Gmail page, go to the Labels tab
>      in Settings, then click the show link next to the Trash label.)
> 3. Locate the message you'd like to move to your inbox, and check the box next to the sender's name.
> 4. Click Move to Inbox.

I'm guessing from the way you worded your question that you access your emails using the Gmail site (Ie, not using Outlook, Thunderbird etc)? If you do use one of these apps there may be ways, otherwise I think your out of luck pal.